# How to convert a html table into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, html-table

`pandas` provides an useful `to_html()` to convert the `DataFrame` into the `html table`. Is there any useful function to read it back to the `DataFrame`?

Comment: I think not, but it shouldn't be too hard with a little help from `lxml`...

Comment: Also, the conversion to `html` is lossy, as type informations is lost so you would need to specify it yourself. Anyway if the `df` is relatively simple (for example uniform data types) the conversion should take only few lines of code.

Comment: pandas has some type inference methods that attempt to alleviate this problem and they do a pretty good job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.html.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas.io.html.read_html) utility released in pandas 0.12

Answer (score 3):

In the general case it is not possible but if you approximately know the structure of your table you could something like this:

```
# Create a test df:
>>> df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
>>> df
     a           b           c           d           e
0    0.675006    0.230464    0.386991    0.422778    0.657711
1    0.250519    0.184570    0.470301    0.811388    0.762004
2    0.363777    0.715686    0.272506    0.124069    0.045023
3    0.657702    0.783069    0.473232    0.592722    0.855030
```

Now parse the html and reconstruct:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(df.to_html())
columns = d('thead tr').eq(0).text().split()
n_rows = len(d('tbody tr'))
values = np.array(d('tbody tr td').text().split(), dtype=float).reshape(n_rows, len(columns))
>>> DataFrame(values, columns=columns)

     a           b           c           d           e
0    0.675006    0.230464    0.386991    0.422778    0.657711
1    0.250519    0.184570    0.470301    0.811388    0.762004
2    0.363777    0.715686    0.272506    0.124069    0.045023
3    0.657702    0.783069    0.473232    0.592722    0.855030
```

You could extend it for Multiindex dfs or automatic type detection using `eval()` if needed.